# Call File.readlines (or equivalent) on zipped files WITHOUT unzipping them first

Tags: ruby, gzip

I'm trying to write a rake task to scan through some zipped up log files and extract some data that i can then use to update some database records.  Because of space limitations on our server i can't unzip all of the files and just call File.readlines on them which is what i would normally do.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach that doesn't involve unzipping the files?  What i need to do is basically scan for lines matching a particular regex, then extract some text from the line AFTER the matched line.  They are all gzipped, and are therefore .gz files.

Comment: Basically you want to text-match compressed data without uncompressing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the gzipped file using Ruby, and perform your searching as if you had opened the file as normal, like this:

```
require 'zlib'

Zlib::GzipReader.open("myfile.gz") { |gz|
  # place your code here, something like:
  p gz.readlines.grep /my-magic-marker/
}
```

This will load the entire file in memory, beware of that.